# Unity - How to make grass details look good from top-down

Tags: unity

I have an issue with the terrain details. Since it only draws a single plane per texture, it looks quite crappy with a angled top-down camera, for example for an RTS camera.

Is there some way around this, I know one solution people use is to angle the grass towards the camera a bit, but that isnt possible with the terrain details painter.

The issue is circled in red:

[image]

If there is no solution to this, are there some techniques I can use to make some interesting-looking grass for an RTS camera?